# SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet doesn't work

Tags: mysql, linux, centos5

I found out how to change the default value of `max_allowed_packet` in MySQL using `SET GLOBAL`. However, each time I used this command, the default value stayed untouched! 
I used these commands:

```
mysql --user=root --password=mypass
mysql> SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=32*1024*1024;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 secs)
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES max_allowed_packet;
```

And then the result is max_allowed_packet = 1048576. What am I missing?

Comment: Breeze, at this point in time, 7 years later, SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'; should show you a 32MB number - depending on version.  Many details have changed in 7 years.  Also, SET GLOBAL xxx=xx applies to NEW CONNECTIONS to the instance.  If your configuration is not successfully changed, and you stop/start your instance, you will have the same value you had on past days.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Hmmmm.. You have hit this [NOT-A-BUG](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=52802) it seems. :)

> If you change a global system variable, the value is remembered and used for new
>   connections until the server restarts. (To make a global system variable setting
>   permanent, you should set it in an option file.) The change is visible to any client that
>   accesses that global variable. However, the change affects the corresponding session
>   variable only for clients that connect after the change. The global variable change does
>   not affect the session variable for any client that is currently connected (not even that
>   of the client that issues the SET GLOBAL  statement).

Refer [this](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=52805) too. Read Shane Bester explanation.

You should change from the my.ini/my.cnf file and restart the server for the max_allowed_packet setting to take effect.

Comment: except the "bug" is closed as "not a bug".

Comment: thank you sir for your propmt reply .
but i tried restarting mysql after that , still im getting the 1 Mb limit !

Comment: @J-16 SDiZ, Yup they have marked the issue as Not-a-bug(Issue, Which is still confusing for us).

Comment: @Hossein, Did you change it from my.ini/my.cnf and restarted the server?

Comment: @Ashwin A : no sir , after issuing the command "SET GLOBAL ..." i exited the mysql and restarted it . 
i thought that would enough . i try to edit the my.ini/my.cnf and report back .
by the way thank you again

Comment: @AshwinA : Thank you sir , your solution worked flawlessly :) 
by the way do i need to enter anything else to avoid any conflict ? 
such as changing the value of net_buffer_length ?

Comment: A note to RedHat users to add here: reloading mysqld after changing the variable in the config file doesn't do anything, a full mysqld restart is required

Answer (score 8):

After running

```
set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000;
```

you have to restart mysql before

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'
```

will show the new value.

I have this issue when restarting mysql through the MAC OSX system preferences and the value hadn't changed. So by logging into mysql via console

```
mysql -u root -p
```

changing it and then restarting mySql seemed to work. Might have been a OS X quirk though.

Answer (score 5):

For those with a MariaDb configuration the problem could be that the **max_allowed_packet** variable is overwritten by a configuration file called later.

In my case I tried to import a database and the server answered me:
**ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 736: MySQL server has gone away**

I discovered that the file:

```
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
```

is called later

```
/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
```

I tried continuously changing in the "mysql.cnf" file but the value was overwritten in "50-server.cnf".

So the solution is to enter the file

```
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
```

and instead of
**"max_allowed_packet = 16M"**
put the desired value as an example
**"max_allowed_packet = 64M"**

Comment: did the trick for me, then I ran `service mariadb restart`, and `service apache2 restart`.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this problem as well and in my case I have multiple versions of MySql installed. 
Adding this note for anyone who might have setup MySql using homebrew on **mac** and are having trouble setting `max_allowed_packet` value in your `my.cnf` file.

The most key information that helped was that the `my.cnf` file can be present in different locations (excerpt from https://github.com/rajivkanaujia/alphaworks/wiki/Install-MySQL-using-Homebrew) -

```
/usr/local/etc/my.cnf  -->  Global Access
/usr/local/etc/my.cnf  -->  Global Access
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.18/my.cnf   --> Sever Level Access
~/.my.cnf   --> User Level Access
```

Since I installed MySql 5.6 via Home brew I found it at -

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql\@5.6/5.6.43/my.cnf
```

Steps followed -

- Update the `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql\@5.6/5.6.43/my.cnf` file under `[mysqld]` group with the necessary `max_allowed_packet value` -

  `[mysqld]
  max_allowed_packet=5G`
- Restart mysql using brew services -

  `brew services restart mysql@5.6`
- Connect/Reconnect to the mysql shell and verify that the configuration has taken effect using -

  `show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';`

Comment: Requesting 5G for max_allowed_packet is likely to be limited to the maximum found in this URL  - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick way to see the variable for anybody who comes across this. To get the value back you need to run

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'
```

Comment: OP did this, and it did not return the expected value for reasons outlined in the accepted answer.