# how to change mysql general log path

Tags: mysql, logging

I  change mysql general log from "/var/lib/mysql/general.log" to "/test/general.log",but failed.

```
root@iZbp1606ryhhy2d1cq7h12Z:/test# ll /
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    root     4096 Mar  9 15:23 test/

root@iZbp1606ryhhy2d1cq7h12Z:/test# ll /test/
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql 4096 Mar  9 15:23 mysql/
```

After mkdir  "/test/mysql" and set permission. then log into mysql, with below command.

```
mysql -uroot -p
mysql> set GLOBAL general_log_file = '/test/mysql/gen.log';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> set GLOBAL general_log =1;
ERROR 29 (HY000): File '/test/mysql/gen.log' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

how can I change mysql defalt path to "/test/mysql/gen.log"

Comment: fix "/var/lib/mysql/general.log" to "/test/mysql/general.log" ,

Comment: mysql version is 5.7.  I want to change general_log path without restarting mysql server.

Answer (score 1):

Goto  /etc/mysql/my.cnf. You will get log_error and general_log flag where you can set new log path accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, But I can not restart mysql server, mysql version is 5.7, how to change general path without restarting.

Comment: There is query  " set global general_log_file = 'log_file_path'; ".  It seems it is also not working without server get restart. Just refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922894/set-global-max-allowed-packet-doesnt-work