# change max_allowed_packets doesn't work even after edited php.ini

Tags: mysql

This may look like a duplicate to [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922894/set-global-max-allowed-packet-doesnt-work) but i followed the solution from the answer yet it still doesn't work. I'm using XAMPP by the way.
This is how I do it.

```
 mysql -u root -p
 mysql> SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=33554432;
 Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 secs)
 mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
```

After that I restart mysql then go back and the result is still max_allowed_packet = 1048576 .

Then I added, not edited, this lines of code into php.ini at the very bottom of the code because those lines does not exist in the php.ini file.

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 32M
[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet = 32M
```

Restart again. Check the max_allowed_packet and it still the same 1048576 bytes.
Are they any more solutions to fix it so I can upload files larger than 1MB? Or did i do something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`max_allowed_packet` is a MySQL Server system variable.

The setting of the system variable can be specified in the `my.cnf` file, under the `[mysqld]` section.

It can also be supplied as an option in the mysqld_safe start command; but don't do that. Just add it to the `my.cnf` file.

(MySQL Server hasn't a foggy notion of what a `php.ini` file is.)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet

Comment: oh i was the one confused php.ini with my.ini. thanks for pointing it out!